# How to mass format window files sorting and view style for my entire computer?

Tags: windows-7, sorting, user-folders

When going into a folder of a window, I usually do 1) right click > view > list, then 2) right click > sort by > type.

It gets annoying when I have to do this every time I am in a new folder, and also for some folders (like dropbox), this specified format will revert back to default from time to time.

How can I set it once so 1) and 2) above will be the default for all the files in any folder of my entire computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows gives you five "types" of folders that you can configure **and save** the display settings for:

- General Items
- Documents
- Pictures
- Music
- Videos

I wasn't able to find any documentation from Microsoft, but there's [a good HowToGeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/) that describes this in detail.

The trick is the "Apply to Folders" button below in Folder Options.  After customizing your settings, click that button to save it (and apply it to other folders of the same "type").

[image: Folder Options]